how can I use preg match to match several strings?
I wrote a preg_match to block spam in my form comments that works fine (this blocks web page URL insertion and 2 phrases, and throws a message, which also stops the send.):
$error_message = "";
if(preg_match('/http|www|working capital|you tired/i',$comments)) {
    $error_message .= "This is not allowed.<br />";
  }

I want to add another preg_match that does the exact same thing for another string/form field.
I want to also use this expression to block similar injections into my name field:
$error_message = "";
if(preg_match('/http|www/i',$name)) {
    $error_message .= "This is not allowed.<br />";

On the comments example I tried   ,$comments, $name (with and without the space) but it didnt work, and also using both Preg_match expressions separately which resulted in only the last one working, not both.
I would guess I could do the same thing for all my form fields, like numbers to validate phone numbers?  Maybe a third expression like this:
if(preg_match('/^[0-9]{10}+$/', $telephone)) {
echo "Valid Phone Number";
} else {
echo "Invalid Phone Number";
}

I have these in my php submit file as the spammers go right to my php code, bypassing any blocks in my form itself.  How do I use both or several in one php file?
Thank you very much.

To get help you better tag the programming language you use

It seems that you set $error_message to an empty string before doing the second check:
<?php
$error_message = "";
if(preg_match('/http|www|working capital|you tired/im', $comments)) {
    $error_message .= "This is not allowed.<br />";
}

$error_message = ""; // <- remove this
if(preg_match('/http|www/i',$name)) {
    $error_message .= "This is not allowed.<br />";
}

Remove the second
$error_message = "";

and you should see both messages.
Here is a refactored example of you code (https://onlinephp.io/c/e31f8):
<?php

$comments = <<<STR
See inappropriate pix at http://example.com/spam-page
STR;

$name = 'my name is https://example.com/ ';

$telephone = 'invalid number';

$errors = array();

if(preg_match('/http|www|working capital|you tired/im', $comments)) {
    $errors []= "comment contains forbidden keywords";
  }

if(preg_match('/http|www/i',$name)) {
    $errors []= "name must not contain URL";
}

if(!preg_match('/^[0-9]{10,}$/', $telephone)) {
    $errors []= "Invalid Phone Number";
}

if(sizeof($errors) > 0) {
    echo implode('<br>' . PHP_EOL, $errors);
} else {
    // save data
    echo 'success';
}

Please take note that I also modified your telephone regex to match minimum 10 numbers. I assumed thats what it should do.

this did the trick!  Thank you.
Remove the second
$error_message = "";
